# Как узнать, есть ли в конкретном столбце DataFrame значение?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть у меня DataFrame.

Чтобы полноценно его использовать, мне нужно заменить везде "--" на 0.
Сейчас я делаю это так:

```
f['Conversions'].replace(['--'],[0],inplace=True)

f['CostPerConversion'].replace(['--'],[0],inplace=True)

f['ConversionRate'].replace(['--'],[0],inplace=True)

f['AvgPageviews'].replace(['--'],[0],inplace=True)

f['BounceRate'].replace(['--'],[0],inplace=True)
```

Проблема заключается в том, что, если в столбце, к которому я применяю код, все таки нет `--`, происходит ошибка.

Костыль, который я ищу, должен говорить есть ли в столбце данное значение, после чего при при положительном ответе я бы применял код.

Однако, если у вас есть элегантные решения типа "заменить во всем DataFrame `--` на 0, если таковые есть", то подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: По идее `f.replace('--', 0, inplace=True)` должно работать на всем датафрейме. Можете предоставить входные данные, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: У меня решение с костылем было в аналогичном случае немного другое.
Надо было обработать список почтовыми ящиками - не у всех они были в списке. Проблему решил с использованием функции find. С поиском в строке "@". Тоже костыль, но мне идеальный код был не важен)).

Comment: [что делать с ответами на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

Если данный DataFrame получен в результате чтения CSV / Excel файла, то проще всего воспользоваться параметром `na_values=["--"]`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, na_values=["--"]).fillna(0)
```

или

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, na_values=["--"]).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Если вопрос в том как преобразовать все столбцы к числовому типу, то делать это лучше так:

Пример данных:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]:
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   2   3   4   5
1   6  --   8  --  10
2  11  12  13  14  15
3  16  17  18  --  20
4  21  22  23  24  25

In [15]: df.dtypes
Out[15]:
a     int32
b    object
c     int32
d    object
e     int32
dtype: object
```

решение:

```
cols = df.columns[df.dtypes.eq("object")]
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce").fillna(0)
```

результат:

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]:
    a     b   c     d   e
0   1   2.0   3   4.0   5
1   6   0.0   8   0.0  10
2  11  12.0  13  14.0  15
3  16  17.0  18   0.0  20
4  21  22.0  23  24.0  25
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = df.apply(lamdba c: (0 if c == '--'  else c) if c else  0)
```